# Appending new values to dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to have values for every client from clients_grouped dataframe, I mean append values for every key of dictionaries: eve_across_tranches_users, OFRE_prorated_users, KCON_own_funds_requirement_users. The following code unfortunately is returning me these 3 dictionaries with correct values but only from the last client from the loop. How can I change it to receive dictionaries with values for all clients?

```py
bands_factors = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9]
bands_differences = [40, 20, 20, 20, 150]

bands = ("Up to 40%", "40 to 60%", "60 to 80%", "80 to 100%", "100 to 250%", "over than 250%")
bands_sum = 0
i = 0
eve_across_tranches_users = {}
OFRE_prorated_users = {}
KCON_own_funds_requirement_users = {}



for index, row in clients_grouped.iterrows():
    if row["EVE_as_percent"] > 250:
        bands_differences.append(row["EVE_as_percent"] - sum(bands_differences))
    while bands_sum < row["EVE_as_percent"]:
        check_sum = bands_sum
        bands_sum += bands_differences[i]
        if bands_sum > row["EVE_as_percent"]:
            bands_differences[i] = row["EVE_as_percent"] - check_sum
            eve_across_tranches_users[bands[i]] = bands_differences[i] / 100 * client_limit
            OFRE_prorated_users[bands[i]] = eve_across_tranches_users[bands[i]] / row["EVE"] * row["OFRE"]
            KCON_own_funds_requirement_users[bands[i]] = OFRE_prorated_users[bands[i]] * bands_factors[i]
        else:
            eve_across_tranches_users[bands[i]] = bands_differences[i] / 100 * client_limit
            OFRE_prorated_users[bands[i]] = eve_across_tranches_users[bands[i]] / row["EVE"] * row["OFRE"]
            KCON_own_funds_requirement_users[bands[i]] = OFRE_prorated_users[bands[i]] * bands_factors[i]
            i += 1
```

This is how clients_grouped can look like:
[image: screen]

Comment: can you provide clients grouped sample csv?

Comment: Added example clients_grouped df

Comment: I was trying to replace "=" to append but then I have the error: KeyError: 'Up to 40%'

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem by using the code:

```py
bands_factors = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9]
bands_differences = [40, 20, 20, 20, 150]

bands = ("Up to 40%", "40 to 60%", "60 to 80%", "80 to 100%", "100 to 250%", "over than 250%")
bands_sum = 0

eve_across_tranches_users = defaultdict(list)
OFRE_prorated_users = defaultdict(list)
KCON_own_funds_requirement_users = defaultdict(list)


for index, row in clients_grouped.iterrows():
    i = 0
    check_sum = 0
    bands_sum = 0
    if row["EVE_as_percent"] > 250:
        bands_differences.append(row["EVE_as_percent"] - sum(bands_differences))
    while bands_sum < row["EVE_as_percent"]:
        check_sum = bands_sum
        bands_sum += bands_differences[i]
        if bands_sum > row["EVE_as_percent"]:
            bands_differences[i] = row["EVE_as_percent"] - check_sum
            eve_across_tranches_users[bands[i]].append(bands_differences[i] / 100 * client_limit)
            OFRE_prorated_users[bands[i]].append(eve_across_tranches_users[bands[i]][index] / row["EVE"] * row["OFRE"])
            KCON_own_funds_requirement_users[bands[i]].append(OFRE_prorated_users[bands[i]][index] * bands_factors[i])
        else:
            eve_across_tranches_users[bands[i]].append(bands_differences[i] / 100 * client_limit)
            OFRE_prorated_users[bands[i]].append(eve_across_tranches_users[bands[i]][index] / row["EVE"] * row["OFRE"])
            KCON_own_funds_requirement_users[bands[i]].append(OFRE_prorated_users[bands[i]][index] * bands_factors[i])
            i += 1
```